# I want to read data from a line in a file. in Java

Tags: java, line, bufferedreader

I'm currently trying to read certain data from multiple lines(from a specified file) in java.

For example with the lines below i want to store the numerical values from each line in an array, i don't want to read the entire line into an array(i can do that already)

```
      Firstname 100700 Lastname
      Firstname 260000 Lastname
      Firstname 303000 Lastname
      Firstname 505050 Lastname
```

How would i go about putting something in my code which allows the program to read the numerical data in my scenario.(Btw the spaces are supposed to be there)
         BufferedReader input;

```
    input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));// file to be read from
    String Line;
    int i = 0;
    int[]number=new int[4];
    while (Line != null)
    {
        Line = input.readLine(); 

       // Then i would need something down here to read the numerical values?
        number[i]=????

        i++
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: are all the lines in a certain format? you can split the line into tokens using String's `split` method and convert the numerical token into a number using `Integer.valueOf(string)`.

Comment: Cheers for that, the lines are all strings.

Answer (score 2):

Hava a look on [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

You can use `Line.split(" ")` to split your `String` into a `String[]` and then use `Integer.parseInt(myArray[1])` to get the number as an `int`.

Also note: in java, the convention is that variables start with lower case letter, so you should consider renaming `Line` -> `line`

Answer (score 1):

```
input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));// file to be read from
String line;
int i = 0;
int[]number=new int[4];
while (line != null)
{
    line = input.readLine(); 
    // here is my refinement
    String[] x = line.Split();
    System.out.println("FirstName: " + x[0]);
    System.out.println("Number: " + x[1]);
    System.out.println("LastName: " + x[2]);

    i++
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. There is no String.Split(). (it should be .split()    Please make sure the 'code' part of answer compiles/does not have spelling errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String line = input.readLine();
if (line != null) {
   int number = Integer.parseInt(line.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` has `.hasNextInt()` and `.nextInt()`. You can use those to read the numbers. Otherwise you could just use some regexes with the `Pattern` class, or use amit's suggestion.